# Is it possible to get value from previous record in FetchXML?

Tags: fetchxml

As the title states, just wondering if it's possible to make reference to a value in the previous record in FetchXML? I can do this fairly easily in SQL (even without resorting to analytic function LAG) but as FetchXML doesn't allow subqueries, I'm not sure if it's possible to do this? Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current FetchXML specification.